# Will I need to update wallet and miner after the next upcoming (March 2019) fork?

Tags: daemon, hard-fork, miners, update, wallet

I have read about the next upcoming [fork planned for the block 1788000](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/ap6iiw/monero_will_fork_at_block_1788000_march_9th/eg6scc0/) (around the 9th of March). After that block, will I need to update the **Monero** daemon, the wallet, or both? And what about the miner programs?

Thanks in advance for answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as we have done before for the other forks, you'll need to update daemon, wallet, and miner.

As you can see [here](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/5126), the upcoming fork will bring to Monero a new PoW algorithm: the CNv4, Cryptonight variant 4 aka CryptonightR.

Comment: To be precise, CNv4 will be based on CryptonightR. Mostly it, but with a few changes.