# Daemon sync questions

Tags: synchronization, daemon, monero-forks

I've been letting the daemon sync for a while now, a few days actually, and it's at 80% and now going very slowly forward. About 20 blocks at a time. I understand why this happens, but this case seems out of the ordinary from what I've seen from other questions. My question is: can I expect this to slow down further due to block size? I'm a patient man, but I'd like to know what to expect.

Secondly, I read in another question ([Will I need to update wallet and miner after the next upcoming (March 2019) fork?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/10883/will-i-need-to-update-wallet-and-miner-after-the-next-upcoming-march-2019-fork)) that the upcoming fork will require a daemon update. Will this involve another full sync of the daemon? I don't want to let it finish only to have to wait on it for another week.

Thank you in advance! Apologies for the likely common questions or any mix-up in terms, I'm brand new to cryptocurrency and a lot of information is going right over my head.

Answer (score 1):

Hi and welcome to Monero.

Syncing:

I am going to make a guess here and assume you are using a HDD. This will sync slower than an SSD so will take a while to sync. You may also be connected to some slow peers. Be patient or download the raw database and perform an [import](https://ww.getmonero.org/resources/user-guides/importing_blockchain.html). This may actually be slower though, depending on your internet speed.

Upcoming network upgrade:

This will not require a full new blockchain sync. Once you've updated your software, when you run the latest version, it will upgrade the database to the latest version.